# Oracle SQL error message "ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column"

Tags: oracle

I have a table named "airplane" with "Serial_no", "aircraft_model" and "capacity". I want to insert data into the table but I keep getting the error message

```
INSERT INTO "T55878"."AIRPLANE" (SERIAL_NO, AIRCRAFT_MODEL, CAPACITY) 
VALUES ('22768', 'KBH001', '970')
```

> ORA-30667: cannot drop NOT NULL constraint on a DEFAULT ON NULL column
>   ORA-06512: at line 1

I read on various forums that purging your recycle bin can be the answer however when I type in *purge recyclebin;* and run the statement, I only get this:

[image]

Can anyone help me understand what the issue is and how I can fix it. Thank you.

Comment: purge should work fine. Have you tried to insert after that? Oracle keeps track of the tables you dropped (so you can flashback them) and eventually the user recyclebin becomes full.

Comment: I've tried inserting data after purging my recycle bin. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement for the table. Also, please post the exact database version and patch level. This may be a bug with the new DEFAULT ON NULL syntax (based on some limited Googling), but that syntax was only introduced in 12c, so can't think of a reason why this would occur in 11g.

Comment: My database setting says:

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
"CORE 12.1.0.1.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.1.0 - Production

and my CREATE TABLE was:
CREATE TABLE airplae
( serial_id number (5) not null,
aircraft_model varchar2 (10),
capacity number (10),
CONSTRAINT airplane_pk PRIMARY KEY (serial_id)
);